# Placing two blocks in one line

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, page

I want to know how to display two blocks in one line to make a bar ?

When I make two widgets, they are displayed separately or one of them in a second line. How to fix it ?

Comment: Please post the code

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated to give you a precise answer because you haven't published your code and no more information but I try to give you an answer.

Try to put your widjets or your blocks in a div like the code bellow:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        //your block here, or widget
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        //your block here, or widget
    </div>
</div>
```